# In Windows phone speech recognition got this error . 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Tags: c#, async-await, speech-recognition

WP8 speech recognition.
I get this error message for the below code.

```
`Citysearch.DLL!Citysearch.MainPage.MicButton_Click_2(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 70    C#`
```

--

```
   private async void MicButton_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

          if (recoResult.ResultStatus == SpeechRecognitionUIStatus.Succeeded)
          {
              textbox.Text = recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text;


          }

        throw new NotImplementedException();


    }
```

this is the code I wrote to create Mic button in c#. When I wrote it in `xaml` same error got.
I can't figure out why it happens. When I created the button click through the following code. It created that method without `async` . But since I have a speech recognition code like inside that method it requires `async`. I put it then. And I am getting above error. When running the program. What can I do to overcome that problem?

```
ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

                ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
                ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
                ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
                ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

                ApplicationBarIconButton MicButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
                MicButton.IconUri = new Uri("/appbar.microphone.rest.png", UriKind.Relative);
                MicButton.Text = " MicButton";
                ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(MicButton);


                MicButton.Click += new EventHandler(MicButton_Click_2);
```

Any help would be great...

Comment: Did you forget to delete the line "_throw new NotImplementedException();_" in MicButton_Click method?

Comment: I have forgot. But it is not the reason to have this error

Comment: Are you getting the same exception even after removing this code? Also note, the exception is thrown inside a "async void" method. Therefore the exception behavior will be [unpredictable](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2013/11/10/windows81-async-void-exceptions/). Try wrapping the entire method inside a try...catch block and see if it produces a more meaningful exception.

Comment: I tried with try catches and all. but didn't work. But later I wrote a new method async than writing this (  SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();) inside button click. And called that method in the button clicked. that way it worked finally.

Comment: Weird. But glad it worked for you :)